# Cannot find view for view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm unable to locate any views with *Caliburn.Micro*. The bootstrapper starts up, but then a generic window appears that there aren't any views for **ShellViewModel**, even if there's a **ShellView.xaml**. What do?

**Bootstrapper**

```
public sealed class AppBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase
{


    private IKernel _kernel;

    #region Bootstrapper

    public AppBootstrapper()
    {
        Start();
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        _kernel = new StandardKernel();
        _kernel.Bind<IWindowManager>().To<WindowManager>().InSingletonScope();
        _kernel.Bind<IEventAggregator>().To<EventAggregator>().InSingletonScope();
        _kernel.Bind<IShell>().To<ShellViewModel>();
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(object sender, System.Windows.StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayRootViewFor(typeof (IShell));
    }

    protected override void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _kernel.Dispose();
        base.OnExit(sender, e);
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        if (serviceType != null) {
            return _kernel.Get(serviceType);
        }

        throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceType");
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        _kernel.Inject(instance);
    }

    #endregion

    }
}
```

**ShellViewModel**

```
 public sealed class ShellViewModel : Screen, IShell
{

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        DisplayName = "Hello";
    }

}
```

Comment: Is logging turned on?

Comment: @DerekBeattie In Caliburn? How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have StartupUri accidentally set in your Application element in App.xaml?

Comment: @DerekBeattie OK, got it. Caliburn posts "View not found. Searched: MyProject.ShellView." Unfortunately, this gets me nowhere since there is a ShellView.xaml residing in my project. :/

Comment: @devdigital No, already checked that.

Comment: Is your ShellViewModel in a ViewModels folder (and namespace), and your ShellView in a Views folder (and namespace). May be worth deleting your ShellView and recreating also, in the correct folder so that a code-behind file is correctly present.

Comment: @devdigital No, it isn't. I separate my views/viewmodels not by type, but per domain concern.

Comment: Have a look at http://blog.beabigrockstar.com/split-views-and-viewmodels-in-caliburn-micro/

Comment: @devdigital Yes, that's splitting view/viewmodels into different assemblies. But that is not what I have too. And structuring view/viewmodels into separate folders is also not a requirement of Caliburn. I'm not sure what you are trying to tell me, sorry.

Comment: Could you post your code somewhere, your situation isn't very clearly described.

Comment: Can you double check the namespace of the view in xaml?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use the override of SelectAssemblies to tell CM where the ".dll"s are for views and viewmodels. otherwise it will never find them.  I usually use this for my project as well and it should solve your problems.